# jquery v javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a function which I need to appear within a jQuery `$(document).ready(function() {}` - I am [au fait](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/au+fait) with javascript but not really worked with jQuery. How can I jQuerify this function?

```
function populateContext()
{
    contextTxtBox = document.getElementById('searchContext');
    pathArr = window.location.pathname.split( '/' );
    contextTxtBox.value = pathArr[1].toUpperCase(); 
};
```

Comment: jQuery is JavaScript, it just offers some functions to make frequently used tasks easier, but also slower.
This task is trivial, and is best left alone with simple Javascript, as it will be faster, and will have less dependences.

Comment: @Alexander. True...but it's trivial in this case.

Answer (score 4):

jQuerify? Make it a plugin!

```
(function($){

    $.fn.populateContext = function(){
        var pathArr = window.location.pathname.split( '/' );
        return this.val(pathArr[1].toUpperCase());
    };


}(jQuery));
```

and use it like this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    // Same as window.onload
    $("#searchContext").populateContext();
});
```

Comment: Shucks, I just used up my last vote elsewhere so I can't up this one. But props for turning it into a plugin! True spirit of jQuery :)

Answer (score 3):

It's actually nearly identical since the only thing I find worth jQuerifying (nice word) is the DOM element.

```
function populateContext()
{
    var contextTxtBox = $('#searchContext');
    var pathArr = window.location.pathname.split('/');
    contentTxtBox.val(pathArr[1].toUppercase());
}

$(document).ready(function()
{
    populateContext();
});
```

Comment: That was a typo, I meant `val()`.

Comment: cane be simplified to $(document).ready(populateContext) if this all you're doing

Comment: can be simplified further to `$(populateContext);` if this all you're doing

Answer (score 1):

this way, if i understand you correctly

```
function populateContext()
{
    contextTxtBox = $('#searchContext');
    pathArr = window.location.pathname.split( '/' );
    contextTxtBox.val(pathArr[1].toUpperCase()); 
};
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
//whatever code you want

});

function populateContext()  {
    pathArr = window.location.pathname.split( '/' );
    $("#searchContext").Val(pathArr[1].toUpperCase()); 
};
```

just a sidenote: jQuery IS javascript so you can mix and match :)

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick

```
function populateContext() {
    var aPath = $( location ).attr( 'href' ).split( "/" );
    $( '#searchContext' ).val( aPath[1].toUpperCase() )
}
```

Comment: I seem to be the only one who is jQuerifying the location :)

Answer (score 0):

```
function populateContext(){
    contentTxtBox = $('#searchContext');
    pathArr = window.location.pathname.split( '/' );
    $(contextTxtBox).val(pathArr[1].toUpperCase());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure aout what you mean, but you could just do:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    populateContext()
});
```

If you want to improve your function to make use of jQuery, you could do this way:

```
function populateContext() {
    var $contextTxtBox = $('#searchContext');
    pathArr = window.location.pathname.split( '/' );
    $contextTxtBox.val(pathArr[1].toUpperCase()); 
};
```

If you provide more information, about what exactly is your doubt, i may be able to explain better.

Comment: My actual instructions are to add: on DOM loaded function listener 'DomLoaded' -----------

function populateContext()
{
 contextTxtBox = document.getElementById('searchContext');
 pathArr = window.location.pathname.split( '/' );
 contextTxtBox.value = pathArr[1].toUpperCase(); }

// populate the search context
DomLoaded.load(populateContext);

How does Jquery handle listeners??

Comment: It depends on the kind of event you are interested, in your case, is the DOM Ready event, you can simply: $(document).ready(callback); and the jQuery will call the "callback" function when DOM is ready. But i think you should read: http://api.jquery.com/ready/ it will make things more clear :)